# Javascript redirect based on navigator.userAgent

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect a a user when they visit a web page based on the device that they are using to the relevant app store:

```
  //iPhone Version:
     if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
        window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/APP123";
      }

  //Android Version:
     if(navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
        window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.APP.123";
       }
   //Anything Else  
     else {
        window.location.href = "https://example.com";
       }
```

This works perfectly on everything other than iPhone.

I know that the userAgent detects the iPhone part but it then ignores the redirect to the Apple App Store and redirects to example.com

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated

Comment: How do you know this -> `userAgent detects the iPhone part` ?

Comment: I had added in an alert(navigator.userAgent) in the iPhone IF statement and it output was: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU........). I just removed the alert for posting on here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `else if` instead of just `if`:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
  window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/APP123"
} else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
  window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.APP.123"
} else {
  window.location.href = "https://example.com"
}
```

If you don't use an `else if` block then you'll have 2 `if` statements:

- One that checks if it's an iPhone and otherwise does nothing (since there's no `else` block)
- Another that checks if it's an Android and otherwise redirects to https://example.com